# MVC show related data in foreach loop in a view

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I've created a Posts, Comments table and wanted to show the related data in a similar way to this tutorial [link](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Im new to linq and MVC5.

I wanted to display the Post header and when clicked it would show the post details and their comments.

From what I've tried below, I can only get the post table information to show, I cannot display any comments, it just errors out when I put item.Comments.Comment_Content, item.Comment doesnt work.

This is my viewmodel;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using Roe8_2.Models;

namespace Roe8_2.ViewModels
{
    public class PostIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; } 


    }
}
```

This is the controller

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? CommentID)
    {
        var viewModel = new PostIndexData();

        viewModel.Posts = db.Posts
            .Include(p => p.Comment) 
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDate);

        if (id != null)
        {
            ViewBag.PostID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Comments = viewModel.Posts.Where(p => p.PostID == id.Value).SingleOrDefault().Comment;
        }
        if (CommentID != null)
        { 
            ViewBag.PostID = id.Value;
            viewModel.Comments = viewModel.Comments.Where(p => p.PostID == id.Value);
}
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

This is the view;

```
@model  Roe8_2.ViewModels.PostIndexData 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Posts)
    {
        string selectedRow = "";
        if (item.PostID == ViewBag.PostID)
        {
            selectedRow = "success";
        }
        <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.Comment != null)
                    {
                        @item.Comment.Comment_Content;
                    }

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { id = item.PostID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PostID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PostID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PostID })
                </td>
                </tr>
    }

</table>
```

These are the tables;

```
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)] 
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }

  public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Comment_Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; } 
    }
}

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string AspNetUsersID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
            }
        }
        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: How is the commentId getting populated when the Index controller is called?  You populate the posts before checking if Id is null.  You aren't populating the comments before checking if commentId is null.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: I get the following error when I insert the following code;

                @if (item.Comment != null)
                    {
                        @item.Comment.Comment_Content;
                    }


 CS1061: 'ICollection<Comment>' does not contain a definition for 'Comment_Content' and no extension method 'Comment_Content' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Comment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just want to display the Comments.Comment_Content which is related to Posts, I'm assuming EF would handle the keys